# How to encode by group

Tags: stata

I have a data set that looks like this

```
Name    Group  X
Tracy    1     91
Tracy    1     78
Luke     1     82
Tracy    2     65
```

I want to generate a variable that looks like this:

```
Name    Group   X      Name_num
Tracy    1     91      1
Tracy    1     78      1
Luke     1     82      2
Tracy    2     65      1
```

Basically, I want to do a by group `encode` operation. However, Stata does not allow using `by` with `encode`. I also tried to combine `by` with `egen group`. It didn't work either.

Comment: `encode` groupwise would mean different sets of value labels within subsets of data. Stata indeed doesn't allow that. A similar comment applies to `egen`'s `group()`. Neither concept makes sense to Stata. That aside, the code example does not explain exactly what to do. What makes Luke 2 and Tracy 1 in group 1 rather than the other way round?  What does `X` have to do with the problem? Without a rule for your new variable the question can't be answered. Is the criterion first occurrence in the dataset? For that to be other than fragile, you need a time or other order variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this buddy

```
bysort Group (Name) : gen dum = 1 if _n == 1
bysort Group (Name) : replace dum = 1 if Name[_n-1] != Name
bysort Group (Name) : gen myid = sum(dum)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `Luke` gets sorted before `Tracy` in `Group` 1, which is not what the OP wants (although why it is wanted is totally unclear to me).